# Find average of last one year of data from excel rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data looks like this:

```
Date       Sale
06082018   102.98
06092018   87.12 
06102018   20.00
. Data Continues
.
.
07082019   123.45
07092019   81.99
07102019   9.00
```

I want a formula to calculate the average of last 12 months leaving the last month for Sale column.

So for the Average of 07102019 date, will be average of all rows 06092019 to 06092018.

How do I do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVERAGE` + `IF` as array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(($A$2:$A$7>=EDATE($D$2;-13)-1)*($A$2:$A$7<=EDATE($D$2;-1)-1);$B$2:$B$7))
```

or `AVERAGEIFS` as ordinal formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;">="&EDATE($D$2;-13)-1;$A$2:$A$7;"<="&EDATE($D$2;-1)-1)
```

(Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`)

[image]